# Setting /PROFILE Linker Flag for CMake MSVC Target

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

How do I get CMake to always set/add the `/PROFILE` linker flag for the `RelWithDebInfo` MSVC (17) target?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if you're targeting MSVC, and if so use a [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to add `/PROFILE` to the link options for your target if `RelWithDebInfo` is the target.

```
if (MSVC) 
  target_link_options(my_target PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:RELWITHDEBINFO>:/PROFILE>)
endif()
```

`target_link_options` is from 3.13, you can use `target_link_libraries` if you're on an old version.